# Using strcpy to copy elements of an char array to another array

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

So I building a spell checker and I have this as my TrieNode class:

```
class TrieNode{
public:
    bool isWord;
    char word[100][20];
    TrieNode* letter[alphabetSize];
```

I have an insert method inside my Trie class which is:

```
    void insert(TrieNode* root, char* wordInsert);
```

I was able to insert the letters of char* word into my trie

This is what I have for my insert function:

```
void Trie::insert(TrieNode* root, char* wordInsert) {
    TrieNode* currentNode = root;
    int wordLength = strlen(wordInsert);
    for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
        //strcpy(currentNode->word[i], currentNode->letter);
        int index = wordInsert[i]- 'a';
        if(!currentNode->letter[index]){
            currentNode->letter[index] = new TrieNode();
        }
        currentNode = currentNode->letter[index];
    }
    currentNode->isWord = true;

}
```

Now I want to insert the current->letter[i] into my other char* array in my TrieNode class called word

I tried doing

```
strcpy(currentNode->word, currentNode->letter[i])
```

but I get an error saying :

No matching function for call to 'strcpy'

How would I be able to get the elements from the letter array into the array called word which is also in my TrieNode class

Comment: No versions of `strcpy` that I know of take a `TrieNode*` as a parameter. You need a `char *`. Perhaps there's one inside the `TrieNode`.

Comment: Do you mean make the char word[100][20] into ->    char* word[100][20] ?

Comment: Why tag your question with every c++ standard to day? You forgot c++20 anyways.

Answer (score 3):

First of all why you use `char *` and `strcpy` if you tagged you question `c++`?
Its better to use `std::string` to keep strings and probably `std::vector` or `std::array` for arrays. Also, you probably should consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead of plain pointers which you allocating with `new`.

Second, `TrieNode` is not string in itself. It has some strings inside, but you didn't specify which of these inside strings you want to copy.